# Segfault doesn't occur in debugger neither valgrind

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, qt5

I'm trying to debug a C++ Qt5 program but I'm unable, most of times it crashes on quit (when launched from shell).

When it's launched from valgrind or from gdb/lldb it doesn't crash.

I already tried generating a coredump and then loading but the results is helpless, only one frame in `bt`.

The actual code is hosted on [github](http://github.com/hotvic/qsubber).

Valgrind output:

```
$ valgrind --tool=memcheck ./build/qsubber
==27761== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27761== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27761== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27761== Command: ./build/qsubber
==27761== 
==27761== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==27761==    at 0x15D790FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.28)
==27761==    by 0x9733523: ??? (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==27761==    by 0x974CF96: g_signal_emit_valist (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==27761==    by 0x974DE39: g_signal_emit_by_name (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==27761==    by 0x973AC2A: g_object_set_valist (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==27761==    by 0x973B4BB: g_object_set (in /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0.4400.1)
==27761==    by 0x636ECC5: ??? (in /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.0)
==27761==    by 0x62F264C: QStyleFactory::create(QString const&) (in /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.0)
==27761==    by 0x628B704: QApplication::style() (in /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.0)
==27761==    by 0x628BACC: QApplicationPrivate::initialize() (in /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.0)
==27761==    by 0x628BB1E: QApplicationPrivate::construct() (in /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.5.0)
==27761==    by 0x413DFC: main (main.cc:34)
==27761== 
Token: bp5tqvuocvv993496ppnds1j91
Status: 200 OK
==27761== 
==27761== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27761==     in use at exit: 6,490,962 bytes in 30,293 blocks
==27761==   total heap usage: 167,918 allocs, 137,625 frees, 19,981,839 bytes allocated
==27761== 
==27761== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27761==    definitely lost: 5,152 bytes in 32 blocks
==27761==    indirectly lost: 21,255 bytes in 779 blocks
==27761==      possibly lost: 3,977,133 bytes in 7,134 blocks
==27761==    still reachable: 2,305,790 bytes in 21,486 blocks
==27761==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27761== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==27761== 
==27761== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==27761== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==27761== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Update**
I'm not asking to debug this code for me, I need help to debug in this scenario, I've searched a lot and found some SO question/answers but nothing helped me until now so created this question.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry , this site isn't a crowdsourced "debug my project" service

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not asking to debug it for me, I'm asking for help how to debug in this scenario and i give my current app as a example. I've searched a lot, but nothing I found helped me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can offer some general guidelines from experience which might help.  Also, with luck, this answer may be of some help to others with this class of problems, and not specific to your code.

If the crash (when not under debugger) is repeatable, that's good.  Start stubbing out major functional parts of the code, one function at a time.  you don't care if this test code "works" or not, just if it crashes on exit or not.

If you are lucky, it will keep crashing after a few iterations of this, then suddenly, not crash on exit any more.  Examine which ever block of code you just stubbed out out closely.

A segfault is usually either a pointer that wrote off the end of some buffer, or a place where some function puts X bytes on the stack, then pops Y bytes off the stack later on (happened to me once when changing prototypes from 32 to 64 bit types).

You are unlucky if the first bit of code you stub out makes the problem go away, but when you put it back, and try stubbing something else out, it still goes away.  Then you are dealing with something elsewhere in the program messing up your memory, and stubbing out arbitrary code not directly associated with the problem moves things around to make the bug appear or disappear.

One last thing to check, compiler optimization flags.  It's really unlikely, but I have hit honest to goodness compiler bugs in my career.  Try compiling with no optimizations at all and see if it still crashes on exit.  Try compiling with max optimizations too.  See if the behavior changes.

If none of this helps, you are going to have to go line by line looking for memory allocations and free spots and look for a mismatch.

Final thought, memory allocated for an object with local scope inside a function, and returned to the calling program via reference could be invalid, and is maybe trying to be cleaned up on program exit.

Good luck.

Comment: Just what I want, I'll start commenting-out-and-in code and see where it happens. I already done a bit this before asking, but there's a "lot" of code, but I'll go on.